# geschafft oder geschaffen

Tags: meaning, verb, meaning-in-context, conjugation

Geschafft oder geschaffen? Ich verstehe, dass schaffen der Regel der starken Konjugation folgt, wenn es im Sinn von "erschaffen, verursachen" gebraucht wird, zum Beispiel

> Rund 50 Millionen Euro Subventionen soll die rot-grüne Landesregierung
> an die Medienfirma HDO gezahlt haben, die aber nur 25 feste
> Arbeitsplätze **geschaffen** hat.

Ist der Partizip hier korrekt? Wenn schaffen bedeutet einen Erfolg

> Ich habe es geschafft, ich habe die Prüfung geschafft.

dann handelt es sich um die schwache Konjugation. Würden Sie bestätigen oder was ist die genaue Regel? Wird die Verwechslung der beiden partizipialen Formen geduldet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Für einen Deutschlerner wäre es wahrscheinlich einfacher, *schaffen* in seiner starken und seiner schwachen Form als zwei verschiedene Verben zu betrachten, die nur zufällig ein paar Formen gemeinsam haben (schließlich ist auch die Bedeutung ziemlich unterschiedlich).

Die zwei Partizipformen sind nicht austauschbar und würden ziemlich schnell mißverstanden werden (das gilt auch für die beiden Formen des Präteritums *schaffte*/*schuf*)

Zu deinen Beispielen - beide sind richtig und nicht austauschbar. In der Bedeutung "hervorbringen/erschaffen" *muss* das Partizip und das Präteritum als "schaffen/schuf/geschaffen" verwendet werden, in der Bedeutung "erreichen/absolvieren" als "schaffen/schaffte/geschafft".

Vielleicht ist es für den Lerner sehr viel einfacher, *schaffen* **nie** als starkes Verb zu verwenden, sondern ganz einfach - zumindestens beim Formulieren - durch *erschaffen* zu ersetzen - es hat dieselbe Bedeutung (wenn auch etwas "gehobener") und ist nur als starkes Verb vorhanden (auch wenn es in der Umgangssprache oft auch - eigentlich falsch - "schwach" konjugiert wird).